# Как сверстать сменный языковой флаг с формой входа?

Tags: html, css

Как сверстать сменный флаг RU, ENG, CHI и подобную форму входа и регистрации?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: **Вот есть хороший пример**:
https://youtu.be/TZRewM7Gl8s Думаю по видео разберешься и возьмешь что тебе нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Если нечем заняться, то можно посидеть и попробовать написать флаги на HTML+CSS, либо SVG.
Либо же найти наборы флагов.

Если они с острыми углами, то закруглите их через `border-radius`.